# Создание списка (list) путём конкатенации значений данного листа с целыми числами

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, list, for

Задание:

> Используя циклы, напишите код, который создает список (list) путем конкатенации значений данного листа с целыми числами от 1 до (произвольного) n включительно.
> Пример:
>
> для списка `["сосиски", "горчица"]` при `n = 3` результат должен выглядеть так:
>
> `['сосиски _ 1', 'горчица _ 1', 'сосиски _2 ', 'горчица _ 2', 'сосиски _ 3', 'горчица _ 3']`
>
> Исходный список: `sample_list = ["мандаринки", "киви", "лимон"]`

Посоветуйте, как приступить к этому заданию?
Если написать код:

```
list = ["мандаринки", "киви", "лимон"]
for x in range(1, n):
    for y in list:
      print(y)
```

то получается не совсем то. Подскажите, как сделать как в примере. Или, собственно, моё решение тождественно?

Comment: Свои попытки надо приводить. Вам укажут, что сделали неправильно и как исправить. Перебираете сначала цифры, потом с фиксированной цифрой перебираете исходный список. Решается в одну строку.

Comment: @ Михаил Муругов Благодарю за рекомендации: в следующий раз обязательно учту!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(n):
    for el in alist:
        объединяете число и элемент списка
```

или генератором списков:

```
print([el + str(i) for i in range(n) for el in alist])
```

Comment: a если мы хотим сделать ответ как в примере, как мы должны поступить? Если перемножить напрямую лист и числа, получится просто лист. А если требуется получить ответ мандаринки_1, киви_1,  лимон_1 и т.д?

Comment: `el + " _ " +str(i) `.

Comment: Благодарю! А можно ли получить такой же результат, но просто с помощью встроенных циклов? С генератором листа быстро всё получается, но хочется понять, как можно так сделать без него :)

Comment: Так первый же вариант, то же самое `el + " _ " +str(i)` вставьте

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Ниразу не встречал такой способ: новичок совсем :)

Comment: Какой именно способ? Это же два простых цикла

Comment: Я про генератор списков и print(el + "_" +str(i)) Только недавно начал изучать основы Python, поэтому не знал, что так можно соединить и всё будет работать :) Ещё раз благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку надо в задании создать список, для этого надо воспользоваться командой `list.append()`.

Код выглядит так:

```
sample_list = ["мандаринки", "киви", "лимон"]
p='_' # создаём строку с подчёркиванием
x=[] # создаём пустой список куда будут добавляться  новые значения
for i in range(1,4): # запускаем перебор от 1 до 3
  for j in sample_list: # запускаем перебор значений
    y=str(i) # перводим число в строку
    c=j+p+y # делаем конкатенацию строк
    x.append(c) # добавляем элемент в список    
print(x)
```